# Trying to store login history inside laravels basic exampel for "manually authenticating users"

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, logging

I used Laravel's guide to authenticating users manually at this link:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#remembering-users

and now I want to log every login's browser, version, platform, and ip.

My function on login:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
       'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 1], $request->remember)) {
        $browserDetails = get_browser($request->header('User-Agent'), true);
        LoginHistory::create([
           'user_id' => auth()->guard('admin')->user()->id,
            'user_type' => '2', // Admin = 2
            'browser' => $browserDetails['browser'],
            'browser_version' => $browserDetails['version'],
            'platform' => $browserDetails['platform'],
            'ip_address' => $request->ip()
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
    }
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors('Username or password incorrect.');
}
```

but I am getting:

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
```

on this line:

> 'user_id' => auth()->guard('admin')->user()->id,

What should I do? The authentication works if I try to access login it will redirect me to dashboard so the session is created, but why can I not access the user id inside this function? It works on the edit admins page showing user id and all information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `auth()->user()->id`. when attempt () is executed and this is successful it performs the authentication

Comment: This did not work. Its not getting the user for some reason